# iOS 17 Beta crash: -[NSCountableTextLocation compare:] receiving unmatching type (null)

Tags: ios, ipados, ios17

Unable to find the cause... but the stacktrace is this!

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCountableTextLocation compare:] receiving unmatching type (null)'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000012083f88a __exceptionPreprocess + 242
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000117674894 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000012083f768 -[NSException initWithCoder:] + 0
    3   UIFoundation                        0x000000014ee60aa5 -[NSCountableTextLocation compare:] + 200
```

Comment: You can try adding an exception breakpoint. This would help you locate the piece of code which is causing the crash.  Once you have the relevant code, please update your question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17802662/how-to-add-exception-breakpoint-in-xcode

Comment: same issues here.

Comment: I'm also seeing these crashes in Crashlytics. Only iOS 17 Beta users are affected. I was unable to reproduce this issue, so an exception breakpoint doesn't help.

Comment: There's also a thread in apple dev forums for this: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/734485

Comment: This happens too frequently in nearly every app. It happens after typing for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I removed all the constraints on the UITextField and added them again. This is the only thing I did.